# What is a German word to describe German's ability to have a word for anything?

Tags: idiom

German is often described as "having a word for everything" since it's agglutinative and express complex ideas or things with a single compound word like 'Schadenfreude', 'Kummerspeck', 'Backpfeifengesicht', or 'Torschlusspanik'. My question is whether there is a German word to describe this state of being able to express nearly anything with a single word (idiomatic or not). A dictionary isn't as useful here as I figure it could be idiomatic and may have to look through many different words for state or condition and their combinations e.g I figure I could look up Zustand and search but don't see anything.

Comment: For me the word you search for is "präzise" but I assume, this is not "präzise" enough for your needs :)

Comment: Ein stark revisionsbedürftiger Gemeinplatz.

Comment: The fact that English puts spaces within compound phrases and German doesn't is a largely irrelevant accident of contingent orthography development. There is no linguistically relevant difference.

Comment: @KilianFoth I'm not a linguist but it does seem somewhat relevant that in English I would have a breath between words in a compound phrase whereas in German there isn't one. In either case I just wanted to know how I could say that, no need to take offense.

Comment: Then you're probably loooking for "Worterfindenbismanblauimgesichtwirdfähigkeit"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linguistic term for word construction is

> [Wortbildung a)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wortbildung).

The ability to construct new words is therefore *»Wortbildungsfähigkeit«*.

In a metaphorical sense this language feature can be called *»Baukastensystem«* (unit construction system) or even *»Wortfabrik«* (word factory).

Answer (score 4):

We don't, and the word is *die Wortfindungsfähigkeit*.

Comment: Ja - oder auch *Wortreichtum", *Ausdrucksreichtum*, *Nuanciertheit* oder tausend andere Möglichkeiten, auszudrücken, daß man auf Deutsch viele Worte einfach erfinden bzw. bei Bedarf zusammenbauen kann.

Comment: More like Wort*er*findungsfähigkeit! :-)

Comment: Oder _Wortschöpfungsleichtigkeit_.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are searching for a word to express "word richness" or "word expresiveness", i.e, *Wortreichtum* and *Wortausdruckskraft*.

Comment: "Wortschatz" kenne ich, aber "Wortreichtum" habe ich noch nicht gehört.